# How much damage constitutes an assist?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I injured someone and he killed me, then after a long interval he was killed and I was awarded an assist to my surprise.

So, since it's obviously not based on time duration, how much do you need to damage someone to earn an assist?

Comment: I think it's just that you contribute damage that helps a kill. So for example if you do 30 damage and someone does 75 you get assist credit, but if you do 50 damage and he does 100+ with a headshot, your damage didn't matter so you don't get the assist. Might be completely wrong!

Comment: Damn teammates and their accurate shooting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe (based on much playing) that you have to deal at least 50% of the total damage the player received.  This would jive with what most professional leagues consider an assist.  So for instance player A deals 60 damage to player C and player B gets the kill dealing 50 damage.  Total damage to Player C = 110.  60/110 = ~.55.  Now if player A deals 90 damage to player C and player B deals 400 damage to player C (awp headshot) player A will not get the assist because total damage = 490 and 90/490 ~= .18.  This is also why you never see a "double assist"

Comment: This seems awfully precise for a guess.  Do you have any sources to back it up?  Have you done any actual experiments to verify?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it only appears to be precise.  My source is playing competitive CS for 8 years and knowing how major leagues implement the assist policy (MLG, CEVO, ESEA).  Since GO was designed with competition in mind it would stand to reason that this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen you need 40+ and you get the assist. My sources - 80 hours of play time.

Comment: this is only a guess, but if a second teammate causes more damage than you did to an opponent and then a third teammate finishes the opponent out. you will not get an assist.